# Using Abax library in mac os c++

Tags: c++

How to use abax library in mac os?
https://github.com/exeray/abaxenabler

after installing library it said no such files.

Comment: Can you offer a bit more detail? As it stands this is unlikely to be enough for someone to replicate the problem you are having.